# Vertical aligning the div in div that was using margin-auto

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have this jsfiddle: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5peh12th/)

As you can see 2 divs are align together side by side, what I want is to `vertically aligning` them. Also I want to be able to add another div to float to the right which is also vertical aligned.

How can I able to aligned them without using absolute positioning?

```
<div style="background-color: blue; ">
        <!-- Global Header -->
        <div class="header">

            <div class="floatLeft">
                <a href="" class="header-logo">WritePub</a>
            </div>

            <div id="pcontainer" class="inner-header-search floatLeft">
                <input type="text"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is too noisy. If you want to vertical align the contents of a div without touching its height you can add "display: table-cell" to the div to simulate a table row column which gives you alignment.

http://jsfiddle.net/5peh12th/2/

```
<div class="container">
    Hello: <input type="text-box"/>
</div>

.container {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

or you can just not give the div a height and give top and bottom padding of equal numbers

Comment: I mean the elements of the red div needs to be aligned vertically